# Firebase BigQuery migration bash error

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I am using the standard workflow of Google to run the migration from the old dataset to the new dataset ([Migration steps](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7029846)). I imputed the missing values, such as Property ID, BigQuery ID, etc. When I ran the bash script the following error occured?

```
Migrating mindfulness.com_mindfulness_ANDROID.app_events_20180515
--allow_large_results --append_table --batch --debug_mode --destination_table=analytics_171690789.events_20180515 --noflatten_results --nouse_legacy_sql --parameter=firebase_app_id::1:437512149764:android:0dfd4ab1e9926c7c --parameter=date::20180515 --parameter=platform::ANDROID#platform --project_id=mindfulness --use_gce_service_account
FATAL Flags positioning error: Flag '--project_id=mindfulness' appears after final command line argument. Please reposition the flag.
Run 'bq help' to get help.
```

On stackoverflow and Google I couldn't find a solution. Someone any idea how to solve this?

My migration.sh script (with small modifications to the IDs to stay anonymous)

```
# Analytics Property ID for the Project. Find this in Analytics Settings in Firebase
PROPERTY_ID=171230123
# Bigquery Export Project
BQ_PROJECT_ID="mindfulness" #(e.g., "firebase-public-project")
# Firebase App ID for the app.
FIREBASE_APP_ID="1:123412149764:android:0dfd4ab1e1234c7c" #(e.g., "1:300830567303:ios:
# Dataset to import from.
BQ_DATASET="com_mindfulness_ANDROID" #(e.g., "com_firebase_demo_IOS")
# Platform
PLATFORM="ANDROID"#"platform of the app. ANDROID or IOS"
# Date range for which you want to run migration, [START_DATE,END_DATE]
START_DATE=20180515
END_DATE=20180517
# Do not modify the script below, unless you know what you are doing :)
startdate=$(date -d"$START_DATE"  +%Y%m%d) || exit -1
enddate=$(date -d"$END_DATE"  +%Y%m%d) || exit -1
# Iterate through the dates.
DATE="$startdate"
while [ "$DATE" -le "$enddate" ]; do
# BQ table constructed from above params.
BQ_TABLE="$BQ_PROJECT_ID.$BQ_DATASET.app_events_$DATE"
echo "Migrating $BQ_TABLE"
cat migration_script.sql | sed -e "s/SCRIPT_GENERATED_TABLE_NAME
$BQ_TABLE/g" | bq query \
    --debug_mode \
    --allow_large_results \
    --noflatten_results \
    --use_legacy_sql=False \
    --destination_table analytics_$PROPERTY_ID.events_$DATE \
    --batch \
    --append_table \
    --parameter=firebase_app_id::$FIREBASE_APP_ID \
    --parameter=date::$DATE \
    --parameter=platform::$PLATFORM \
    --project_id=$BQ_PROJECT_ID
temp=$(date -I -d "$DATE + 1 day")
DATE=$(date -d "$temp" +%Y%m%d)
done
exit
# END OF SCRIPT
```

Comment: The error message is telling you the problem, right? You need to move the `--project_id` argument earlier (before the `query` command).

Comment: Like Elliot said, there error is right there in front of you :) _"FATAL Flags positioning error: Flag '--project_id=mindfulness' appears after final command line argument. Please reposition the flag."_

Comment: Well, the comment in the script says _"Do not modify the script below, unless you know what you are doing :)"_. I'm not really sure what I'm doing so asked for expert help;). I tried to fix the error as you explained and with some research about [flags](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference). 

I tried 2 solutions:
1. I moved  _"--project_id=$BQ_PROJECT_ID"_ to the line exactly in between _"bq"_ and _"query"_. This gave an error.
2. I moved the same line directly after _"query"_, this gave the same error (in next comment field)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the output of your script, it contains this bit of text, right before the flag that's out of order:

`--parameter=platform::ANDROID#platform --project_id=mindfulness`

I'm pretty sure you want your platform to be `ANDROID`, not `ANDROID#platform`.

I suspect you can fix this just by putting a space between the end of the string, and the inline comment. So you have something like this:

`PLATFORM="ANDROID" #"platform of the app. ANDROID or IOS"`

Although to be safe, you might want to remove the comments entirely at the end of each line.